# WARN [ErraiMarshalling] using dynamic marshallers

Tags: java, gwt, errai

I'm trying to figure out why this Warning is showing up, as my Errai app loads in GWT Dev mode:

> [INFO] WARN [ErraiMarshalling] could not locate marshaller class.
>   [INFO] WARN [ErraiMarshalling] using dynamic marshallers. dynamic
>   marshallers are designed for development mode testing, and ideally
>   should not be used in production. *

I have tried to put:

```
<extraJvmArgs>-Xmx1500m -XX:MaxPermSize=1000m -XX:-UseSplitVerifier -Derrai.marshalling.server.classOutput=${project.build.outputDirectory}</extraJvmArgs>
```

and this

```
<outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ErraiApp.properties`, add the following configuration:

```
errai.marshalling.use_static_marshallers=true
```

More on https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ERRAI/ErraiApp.properties

Comment: I had to use: errai.marshalling.force_static_marshallers

Answer (score 0):

This warning message is showing because [MappingContextSingleton.java](https://github.com/errai/errai/blob/master/errai-marshalling/src/main/java/org/jboss/errai/marshalling/server/MappingContextSingleton.java) has method like,

```
  private static void dynamicMarshallingWarning() {
    log.warn("using dynamic marshallers. dynamic marshallers are designed" +
        " for development mode testing, and ideally should not be used in production. *");
  }
```

It called from loadDynamicMarshallers method,

```
public static ServerMappingContext loadDynamicMarshallers() {
    dynamicMarshallingWarning();
```

As I show this error message in three cases like

**Case 1**

```
  if (cls == null) {
      return loadDynamicMarshallers();
    }
```

**Case 2**

```
if (!MarshallingGenUtil.isUseStaticMarshallers()) {
        sContext = loadDynamicMarshallers();
      }
```

**Case 3**

```
catch (Throwable t) {
          log.debug("failed to load static marshallers", t);
          log.warn("static marshallers were not found.");

          sContext = loadDynamicMarshallers();
        }
```

This is not your question's answer but it might help you.